# How to view items in array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting `Subscript out of range` on `Debug.Print myarr(i)`.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim myarr as Variant, i as Long
myarr = Array(ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))

For i = LBound(myarr) To UBound(myarr)
    Debug.Print myarr(i)
Next i
```

I have validated the range with (below) which shows A2:A5

```
Msgbox ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Address (false, false)
```

---

I have also tried changing `myarr` to

```
 = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) 
 = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
 = Array(Temp.Range("A2:A" & Temp.Range("A" & Temp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
```

First one gives `Subscript out of range`, 2nd two give `type mismatch`

Fairly new to working with arrays, and I dont know what I'm missing here. **Am I loading the array incorrectly or trying to view the items in array incorrectly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myarr` is a two dimesional array with one column.

You will need to add the references to the second dimension.

```
Debug.Print myarr(i,1)
```

Also to load an array from a range you simply assign the value:

```
myarr = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

so

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim myarr as Variant, i as Long
myarr = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = LBound(myarr,1) To UBound(myarr,1)
    Debug.Print myarr(i,1)
Next i
```

Comment: So loading the array this way was my 3rd attempt. But it wasn't working because I was not referring to the array as two dimensional. Dots: Connected.

Answer (score 0):

to add, you can view your array size and elements in [VBA Locals Window](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/debugging/locals-window.htm) (Developer-> Visual basic -> View -> Locals). it really helpful for code compiling and i have it on all the time.